# Having `Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidType` in Neo4j

Tags: java, database, neo4j

While running the following query in Neo4j

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///home/peppa/database/ap/aC.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Aporte {Organization: line[1] ,ruc: line[2] , year: line[4] ,date: line[6] ,process: line[7] ,LastName: line[8] ,LastNameM: line [9] ,Name: line[10] ,DocType: line[11] ,DocNum: line[12] ,TypeAp: line[13] ,Nature: line[14]})
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected 10 to be a java.lang.String, but it was a java.lang.Long
```

Don't know if the file is bad structured or my query is wrong. Please Help!!.

EDIT: I keep having the same issues with the following query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:////home/peppa/database/aP/AC.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Ap  {dni: toint(line[1]) ,rc: toint(line[0])})
```

PD: I already tried without `toint`.

Here is some of the data I'm working with:

```
"20501723844","06747807"
"20501723844","00803710"
"20501723844","40596835"
"20501723844","41696842"
"20501723844","27241420"
"20501723844","19249405"
"20501723844","23154926"
"20501723844","25446127"
"20501723844","18016385"
"20501723844","07093664"
"20501723844","07286049"
"20501723844","21140951"
"20501723844","10291445"
"20501723844","08866233"
"20501723844","09684232"
"20501723844","28297360"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the hints available here.

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

May be that your dataset has something not expected

Comment: I want to know what they mean by "not expected", I thought It reads everything as String by default.

Comment: Could you paste some data here?

Comment: Does it work with a little file? You should check BOM byte, special character or more

Comment: :( doesn't work with a little file. I tried with this [data](http://pastebin.com/ZcxVWWbE) only, still doesn't work :(. btw the file codification is UTF-8.

Comment: Don't even work with just this line: "20510812779","06813446" on the file ( I removed `WITH HEADERS` )

Comment: I have just tested it from the browser and it works with your sample file. May be that there is something "dirty" in your file. I run this: USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///private/tmp/testImport' AS line
CREATE (:Ap  {dni: toint(line[1]) ,rc: toint(line[0])})

Comment: Would you please tell me which codification your csv is using? I just checked mine and is happens to be `ASCII text` , if you are in ubuntu or similar you can check it with the utility `file`. For some reason i can't change the codification I guess i'm going to try to change it.

Comment: Also for me 
ALESSANDROs-MacBook-Air:tmp ale$ file testImport 
testImport: ASCII text
I think that there is something in the file that is wrong that cannot be seen try with od command

Comment: Well it end up working, I not sure what I did to be honest. I just copied your code. Dunno what's happening. Anyways thanks so much! :)